# DataflowBlock.Complete() supposedly stops the block from producing more messages, what happens to the queued items?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

The documentation of `.Complete()` says the following:

> Signals to the `IDataflowBlock` that it should not accept nor produce
>   any more messages nor consume any more postponed messages.

So let's say I have a `BatchedJoinBlock` that I want to complete when its source block completes, but I can't propagate because the links are on predicates:

```
block1.LinkTo(block2.Target1, predicate);
block1.LinkTo(block2.Target2, !predicate);

await block1.Completion;
block2.Complete();
```

So according to the documentation that last line will stop `block2` from producing new messages, but the problem is that `block1` completes as soon as `block2` has accepted all its messages, but these accepted messages might not be processed yet, so what happens to them if `block2` can't produce new messages?

Perhaps I'm misinterpreting *produce anymore messages*?

Comment: Your example will block as you wait for `block1.Completion` but you don't signal completion with `block.Complete`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Complete` means the block will stop accepting more messages, but it **will** process messages it has in its `InputQueue` even though this will result in sending messages forward in the pipeline (as opposed to when the block is faulted because of an exception).

You can see that with this simple example:

```
var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int>(async _ =>
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    return _;
});

var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(_ => Console.WriteLine(_));
transformBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    await transformBlock.SendAsync(i);
}

transformBlock.Complete();
Console.WriteLine("complete");
await transformBlock.Completion;
Console.WriteLine("completed");
```

`complete` will be written immediately but the `TransformBlock` will continue processing the messages and slowly moving them to the next `ActionBlock`.

---

I too am not entirely sure what *"produce anymore messages"* actually means. I'm assuming that it relates to blocks that produce messages and not ones that process incoming messages though I can't think of one.

Comment: `Complete` is defined in `IDataflowBlock` which is included for all block types which is why the documentation mentions sending and receiving.

Comment: @Guvante As you can see in the example `TransformBlock` continues to send messages after `Complete` is called.